# ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb[]) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Having a hard time traversing and querying elements from a `jsonb[]` row.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  work_experience jsonb[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo (id, work_experience)
VALUES (
  'b4e942a0-49b4-4fa7-8f7a-5fbf0541d1c9',
  E'{"{\\"id\\": \\"7cd74bae-ff5b-4f58-ab20-0218f820ffff\\", \\"skills\\": [{\\"id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a|fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Programming languages\\", \\"level2\\": \\"Scripting languages\\", \\"level3\\": \\"TypeScript\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da\\"}, {\\"id\\": \\"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435|686af7e4-6d58-4148-b227-3bf65ff10273\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Software frameworks & libraries\\", \\"level2\\": \\"Frontend frameworks & libraries\\", \\"level3\\": \\"React\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"686af7e4-6d58-4148-b227-3bf65ff10273\\"}, {\\"id\\": \\"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|c4e54726-7bd5-44bb-8597-a05eb2272e2b|cda4441f-dba6-495c-9e2e-7429bd5e0465\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Software frameworks & libraries\\", \\"level2\\": \\"Backend frameworks & libraries\\", \\"level3\\": \\"Node.js\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"c4e54726-7bd5-44bb-8597-a05eb2272e2b\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"cda4441f-dba6-495c-9e2e-7429bd5e0465\\"}, {\\"id\\": \\"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435|fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Software frameworks & libraries\\", \\"level2\\": \\"Frontend frameworks & libraries\\", \\"level3\\": \\"TypeScript\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da\\"}], \\"end_date\\": null, \\"position\\": \\"Senior Software Engineer + Team Lead\\", \\"start_date\\": \\"2019-10-01T00:00:00\\", \\"description\\": \\"Draper, Utah, United States\\\\n• Architected Expert Portal* from the ground up using a Node/Typescript\\\\nbackend, a\\\\nPostgreSQL database, a GraphQL API layer, a Webpack build process, with a\\\\nTypescript/React front-end and XState for state management\\\\n• Enforced coding best practices with linting rules and code formatters by\\\\nautomating it in\\\\ngit workflow\\\\n• Automated deployment Expert Portal* to EC2 instances and the @pluralsight\\\\nNPM\\\\nartifactory using Github, TeamCity, and Octopus\\\\n• Improved product team workflow by building a browser extention to add\\\\nLeanKit card\\\\ntemplate functionality\\\\n• Consumed and published data through Kafka streams and RabbitMQ\\\\nmessages\\\\n• Interviewed, onboarded, and trained junior to mid-level engineers\\", \\"company_name\\": \\"Pluralsight\\"}","{\\"id\\": \\"9e2c2b44-39a4-4369-b237-c51fd938e61d\\", \\"skills\\": [{\\"id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a|012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Programming languages\\", \\"level2\\": \\"Scripting languages\\", \\"level3\\": \\"JavaScript\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024\\"}], \\"end_date\\": \\"2019-10-01T00:00:00\\", \\"position\\": \\"Software Engineer II\\", \\"start_date\\": \\"2017-11-01T00:00:00\\", \\"description\\": \\"Greater Salt Lake City Area\\\\nWorked on the KSL Jobs Classifieds team as a full-stack developer. Following\\\\nthe scrum methodology, I added new features and maintained all things\\\\npowered by KSL Jobs.\\\\n• Built and deployed a \\\\\\"white label\\\\\\" version of KSL Jobs for the Silicon Slopes\\\\nbrand. (https://siliconslopes.ksl.com)\\\\n• Rewrote major sections of the current KSL Jobs site in React.js\\\\n• Automated querying data for reports and analytic purposes through Node and\\\\nPHP scripts\\\\n• Provided rich data tracking through Google Tag Manager, Google Analytics,\\\\nand BigQuery\\\\n• Migrated Solr search engine to ElasticSearch with a GraphQL API\\", \\"company_name\\": \\"Deseret Digital Media\\"}","{\\"id\\": \\"efbf68f4-7bdc-4ab6-bba9-fbf7ec38aeef\\", \\"skills\\": [{\\"id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498|4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Programming languages\\", \\"level2\\": \\"High-level languages\\", \\"level3\\": \\"PHP\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a\\"}], \\"end_date\\": \\"2019-08-01T00:00:00\\", \\"position\\": \\"Full Stack Developer\\", \\"start_date\\": \\"2017-01-01T00:00:00\\", \\"description\\": \\"Provo, Utah Area\\\\nWorked with Appritech LLC to modernize their legacy software and add new\\\\nfeatures to automate their business processes.\\\\n•  Building new call handler from the ground up using JavaScript ES6,\\\\nBootstrap, SASS for\\\\nfront-end, and PHP7/Laravel for back-end\\\\n•  Implemented real-time call management system and built reporting API.\\\\nImproved call agent\\\\nproductivity by 70%\\\\n•  Upgraded deprecated PHP legacy code to PHP 7\\\\n•  Synchronized follow up calls with Twilio API functionality for SMS message\\\\nforwarding\\\\n•  Installed and setup Apache server for an after hours call center\\", \\"company_name\\": \\"Appritech Software\\"}","{\\"id\\": \\"2db60c6c-c214-4d9b-9034-baba676203a8\\", \\"skills\\": [{\\"id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498|4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Programming languages\\", \\"level2\\": \\"High-level languages\\", \\"level3\\": \\"PHP\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a\\"}], \\"end_date\\": \\"2017-09-01T00:00:00\\", \\"position\\": \\"Web Developer\\", \\"start_date\\": \\"2017-02-01T00:00:00\\", \\"description\\": \\"Provo, Utah Area\\\\nWorked with Redcore LLC to build entrepreneurial tools, marketing tools, and\\\\nadding new functionality to the current Wordpress-integrated website and\\\\nCMS.\\\\n• Built Brand Management website from the ground up using Bootstrap and\\\\nJavaScript on the\\\\nfront end, with PHP and MySQL on the back-end\\\\n• Automated managerial and accounting tasks, such as invoice generation,\\\\nand transactions using Stripe API\\\\n• Debugged and perfected current web applications to enrich UX\\\\n• Doubled clientele by expanding Redcore services offered to include website\\\\ncreation and\\\\nmanagement\\", \\"company_name\\": \\"Redcore LLC\\"}","{\\"id\\": \\"c3f1d5b2-5586-477d-ae4c-e2927463244e\\", \\"skills\\": [{\\"id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a|012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024\\", \\"level1\\": \\"Programming languages\\", \\"level2\\": \\"Scripting languages\\", \\"level3\\": \\"JavaScript\\", \\"level1_id\\": \\"c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68\\", \\"level2_id\\": \\"313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a\\", \\"level3_id\\": \\"012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024\\"}], \\"end_date\\": \\"2017-03-01T00:00:00\\", \\"position\\": \\"Software and Web Developer\\", \\"start_date\\": \\"2016-12-01T00:00:00\\", \\"description\\": \\"Provo, Utah Area\\\\nThis internship was focused on building core website and software for\\\\nCentaurific using the LAMP stack.\\\\n• Created dynamic landing pages for products to generate leads\\\\n• Designed a MySQL database to organize data and generate excel reports\\\\n• Revitalized marketing efforts through analytics and a social media sharing\\\\npage\\", \\"company_name\\": \\"Centaurific\\"}"}'
);
```

(Here is what that `work_experience` row looks like in JSON:)

```
[
    {
        "id": "7cd74bae-ff5b-4f58-ab20-0218f820ffff",
        "skills": [
            {
                "id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a|fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da",
                "level1": "Programming languages",
                "level2": "Scripting languages",
                "level3": "TypeScript",
                "level1_id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68",
                "level2_id": "313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a",
                "level3_id": "fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da"
            },
            {
                "id": "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435|686af7e4-6d58-4148-b227-3bf65ff10273",
                "level1": "Software frameworks & libraries",
                "level2": "Frontend frameworks & libraries",
                "level3": "React",
                "level1_id": "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b",
                "level2_id": "e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435",
                "level3_id": "686af7e4-6d58-4148-b227-3bf65ff10273"
            },
            {
                "id": "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|c4e54726-7bd5-44bb-8597-a05eb2272e2b|cda4441f-dba6-495c-9e2e-7429bd5e0465",
                "level1": "Software frameworks & libraries",
                "level2": "Backend frameworks & libraries",
                "level3": "Node.js",
                "level1_id": "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b",
                "level2_id": "c4e54726-7bd5-44bb-8597-a05eb2272e2b",
                "level3_id": "cda4441f-dba6-495c-9e2e-7429bd5e0465"
            },
            {
                "id": "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435|fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da",
                "level1": "Software frameworks & libraries",
                "level2": "Frontend frameworks & libraries",
                "level3": "TypeScript",
                "level1_id": "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b",
                "level2_id": "e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435",
                "level3_id": "fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da"
            }
        ],
        "end_date": null,
        "position": "Senior Software Engineer + Team Lead",
        "start_date": "2019-10-01T00:00:00",
        "description": "Draper, Utah, United Statesn• Architected Expert Portal* from the ground up using a Node/Typescriptnbackend, anPostgreSQL database, a GraphQL API layer, a Webpack build process, with anTypescript/React front-end and XState for state managementn• Enforced coding best practices with linting rules and code formatters bynautomating it inngit workflown• Automated deployment Expert Portal* to EC2 instances and the @pluralsightnNPMnartifactory using Github, TeamCity, and Octopusn• Improved product team workflow by building a browser extention to addnLeanKit cardntemplate functionalityn• Consumed and published data through Kafka streams and RabbitMQnmessagesn• Interviewed, onboarded, and trained junior to mid-level engineers",
        "company_name": "Pluralsight"
    },
    {
        "id": "9e2c2b44-39a4-4369-b237-c51fd938e61d",
        "skills": [
            {
                "id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a|012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024",
                "level1": "Programming languages",
                "level2": "Scripting languages",
                "level3": "JavaScript",
                "level1_id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68",
                "level2_id": "313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a",
                "level3_id": "012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024"
            }
        ],
        "end_date": "2019-10-01T00:00:00",
        "position": "Software Engineer II",
        "start_date": "2017-11-01T00:00:00",
        "description": "Greater Salt Lake City AreanWorked on the KSL Jobs Classifieds team as a full-stack developer. Followingnthe scrum methodology, I added new features and maintained all thingsnpowered by KSL Jobs.n• Built and deployed a "white label" version of KSL Jobs for the Silicon Slopesnbrand. (https://siliconslopes.ksl.com)n• Rewrote major sections of the current KSL Jobs site in React.jsn• Automated querying data for reports and analytic purposes through Node andnPHP scriptsn• Provided rich data tracking through Google Tag Manager, Google Analytics,nand BigQueryn• Migrated Solr search engine to ElasticSearch with a GraphQL API",
        "company_name": "Deseret Digital Media"
    },
    {
        "id": "efbf68f4-7bdc-4ab6-bba9-fbf7ec38aeef",
        "skills": [
            {
                "id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498|4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a",
                "level1": "Programming languages",
                "level2": "High-level languages",
                "level3": "PHP",
                "level1_id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68",
                "level2_id": "f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498",
                "level3_id": "4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a"
            }
        ],
        "end_date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00",
        "position": "Full Stack Developer",
        "start_date": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
        "description": "Provo, Utah AreanWorked with Appritech LLC to modernize their legacy software and add newnfeatures to automate their business processes.n•  Building new call handler from the ground up using JavaScript ES6,nBootstrap, SASS fornfront-end, and PHP7/Laravel for back-endn•  Implemented real-time call management system and built reporting API.nImproved call agentnproductivity by 70%n•  Upgraded deprecated PHP legacy code to PHP 7n•  Synchronized follow up calls with Twilio API functionality for SMS messagenforwardingn•  Installed and setup Apache server for an after hours call center",
        "company_name": "Appritech Software"
    },
    {
        "id": "2db60c6c-c214-4d9b-9034-baba676203a8",
        "skills": [
            {
                "id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498|4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a",
                "level1": "Programming languages",
                "level2": "High-level languages",
                "level3": "PHP",
                "level1_id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68",
                "level2_id": "f45abc59-1e7e-4853-a498-999fcf12d498",
                "level3_id": "4b266297-6e25-4443-90ec-248bded4225a"
            }
        ],
        "end_date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00",
        "position": "Web Developer",
        "start_date": "2017-02-01T00:00:00",
        "description": "Provo, Utah AreanWorked with Redcore LLC to build entrepreneurial tools, marketing tools, andnadding new functionality to the current Wordpress-integrated website andnCMS.n• Built Brand Management website from the ground up using Bootstrap andnJavaScript on thenfront end, with PHP and MySQL on the back-endn• Automated managerial and accounting tasks, such as invoice generation,nand transactions using Stripe APIn• Debugged and perfected current web applications to enrich UXn• Doubled clientele by expanding Redcore services offered to include websitencreation andnmanagement",
        "company_name": "Redcore LLC"
    },
    {
        "id": "c3f1d5b2-5586-477d-ae4c-e2927463244e",
        "skills": [
            {
                "id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68|313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a|012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024",
                "level1": "Programming languages",
                "level2": "Scripting languages",
                "level3": "JavaScript",
                "level1_id": "c8a5328d-87ba-419d-802f-80b1d940bb68",
                "level2_id": "313384d2-486d-4b7f-ba33-76b1cd696f0a",
                "level3_id": "012abcd1-3a6a-4803-a47e-42f46b402024"
            }
        ],
        "end_date": "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
        "position": "Software and Web Developer",
        "start_date": "2016-12-01T00:00:00",
        "description": "Provo, Utah AreanThis internship was focused on building core website and software fornCentaurific using the LAMP stack.n• Created dynamic landing pages for products to generate leadsn• Designed a MySQL database to organize data and generate excel reportsn• Revitalized marketing efforts through analytics and a social media sharingnpage",
        "company_name": "Centaurific"
    }
]
```

I'd like to query out the structure. I tried this and a few other variants of it to no avail:

```
SELECT workexp
FROM foo,
jsonb_array_elements(work_experience) workexp;
```

And I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb[]) does not exist
LINE 3: jsonb_array_elements(work_experience) workexp;
    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Everything I look up has documentation on traversing and querying `jsonb` rows, but not `jsonb[]` ones. How can I query for the "skills"."id"s?

EDIT -- SOLUTION:
All of the solutions given were helpful but I selected [Ramin Faracov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17296084/ramin-faracov) for suggesting to use `unnest`. Thank you!

This is the query that I came up with:

```
SELECT
    id expert_id,
    we_sk->>'id' work_exp_skill_id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        unnest(work_experience)->'skills' we
    FROM foo_json
) sk,
jsonb_array_elements(sk.we) we_sk;
```

Comment: `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense. Use `jsonb` and store a proper JSON array in it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PostgreSQL all `jsonb array functions` only for using `JSONB` types, not `JSONB[]`.

1. First-way you can use `unnest` function to convert arrays to rows, after then you can use `jsonb_array_elements`.
2. Second-way change type `JSONB[]` to `JSON` in your table. Don't worry, you can still insert your JSON string data which is written above into `JSONB` field without any problems. Inside the `JSON` and `JSONB` strings, we can use arrays using formatted strings. `Jsonb array functions` only for arrays written inside JSON string.

Comment: Using unnest helped me fix my query :3

Answer (score 1):

[**db fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=755430eda9693a9fd73b075715f1a31b).

- you don't need `jsonb[]`, just use `jsonb`.
- You need to properly reformat the jsonb, so that you can insert to postgresql.
  I user datagrip syntax highlight to reformat your code to db. like [this](https://prnt.sc/-QXb7ryz3hfQ).
- CTE is more easier to reformat the logic. So i use it.

--query filter mainid then the inner id.
-- "84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435|fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da"

```
with a as (
SELECT workexp
FROM foo_json,
jsonb_array_elements(work_experience) workexp),
b as(select workexp['id'] mainid,
            jsonb_array_elements(workexp['skills']) last_level,
            count(*) over() from  a),
c as(select
         last_level,
    pg_typeof(mainid) from b
    where mainid::text = '"7cd74bae-ff5b-4f58-ab20-0218f820ffff"'::text)
select *,
       last_level['level1'],
       last_level['level2'],
       last_level['level3'],
       last_level['level1_id'],
       last_level['level2_id'],
       last_level['level3_id']
from c
where
    last_level['id']::text
= '"84dff39f-2ed6-408c-a188-14cf55a09c5b|e13b48c1-fd0f-4ecc-89de-58e9312b9435|fd3c41b8-8c15-47e2-a80d-cf3683b2d0da"'::text;
```

--query filter based on mainid (not the inner nested)

```
with a as (
SELECT workexp
FROM foo_json,
jsonb_array_elements(work_experience) workexp),
b as(select workexp['id'] mainid, workexp['skills'], count(*) over() from  a)
select *, pg_typeof(mainid) from b
where mainid::text = '"7cd74bae-ff5b-4f58-ab20-0218f820ffff"'::text;
```

---

**postgresql 15** (dev)
In postgresql 15, there is json_table. make nested json/jsonb query more easier.

```
SELECT jt.* FROM foo_json,
JSON_TABLE(work_experience, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
main_id text path '$.id', start_date date path '$.start_date',
position text path '$.position', company_name text path '$.company_name',
NESTED PATH '$.skills[*]' COLUMNS (
        innerid text path '$.id',
      level2 text, level3 text)
)) jt;
```